# How I can rewrite a query-string based URL only partially

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I want to rewrite the following URL, based on part of its query string, but at the same time, I want to keep the rest of the Query String.

Original URL:

`http://example.com/index.php?route=product/show&item_id=25&show_mobile=true`

To be converted to:

`http://example.com/product/show/?item_id=25&show_mobile=true`

I have searched and found the following wiki on Apache:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

But it hasn't a section for rewriting a single Key&Value pair in Query string and keeping the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close, it's based on the "remove a key" entry from the wiki.  You want to isolate the part that will go into the path in the first capture and use the 2nd capture for the remaining query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(route=[^&]*)&(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1?%2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic rule to capture parameter value of `route` in **any order** from query string and reuse in target URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?route=([^&]*)&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%2?%1%3 [R=301,NE,L]
```